# ten connections block TCP listener, how to unblock

Tags: tcp

Due to multiple `CLOSE_WAIT`s. new connections fail when the total of existing connections and `CLOSE_WAIT`s equals 10.  Where is the 10 connection limit and how can I expand it? (having trouble finding out how to eliminate the `CLOSE_WAIT`, but that is a different question, this question is specifically about how to expand the 10 connection limit.)

Ubuntu  18.04
Kernel: 4.15.0-91-generic
Architecture: x86_64

Output of `netstat --tcp --numeric-ports -p|grep 2225`

```
tcp       15      0 localhost:2225          localhost:42928         CLOSE_WAIT  -                   
tcp        8      0 localhost:2225          localhost:33860         CLOSE_WAIT  10570/mdp           
tcp       15      0 localhost:2225          localhost:41938         CLOSE_WAIT  -                   
tcp       15      0 localhost:2225          localhost:42800         CLOSE_WAIT  -                   
tcp       15      0 localhost:2225          localhost:40912         CLOSE_WAIT  -                   
tcp       25      0 localhost:2225          localhost:33974         CLOSE_WAIT  -                   
tcp        0      1 localhost:51842         localhost:2225          SYN_SENT    12221/telnet        
tcp       15      0 localhost:2225          localhost:41808         CLOSE_WAIT  -                   
tcp        0      0 localhost:33202         localhost:2225          ESTABLISHED 33721/controller    
tcp      481      0 localhost:2225          localhost:33596         CLOSE_WAIT  10570/mdp           
tcp       20      0 localhost:2225          localhost:33582         CLOSE_WAIT  10570/mdp           
tcp        0      0 localhost:2225          localhost:33202         ESTABLISHED 10570/mdp
```

When attempting to connect I get "Connection timed out".
Backlog setting in listen is 5.
App does not (intentionally) limit connections.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us what program is listening on port 2225. If you implemented it, please show the the source code of a [mre].

Comment: the program is mdp, I did implement it and it is the source of the CLOSE_WAIT issue, but as I stated, that is a different question and I don't want this question to get hijacked to that one, the question is where is the 10 connection limit and how to increase it.

Comment: **Please add all requested information to your question,** don't use comments to add information. The limit is probably in your program or in a library you may be using. What error do you get when you try to connect? Connection refused? Connection timed out?

Comment: BTW: The `[mre]` in my first comment shoud mean "minimal reproducible example".

Comment: "Connection timed out" may mean that your application doesn't `accept` the connections. `CLOSE_WAIT` means that the other end has closed the connection but apparently your application did not close the socket. Depending on your implementation these sockets may still block resources like entries in a list of connections.

Comment: I know all that, see my question "what causes this CLOSE_WAIT", but this question is where is the 10 limit and how to increase it?

Comment: BTW thank you for formatting my question more readably

Comment: My guess is that the limit is in your sourcecode, but as you don't show it I cannot find out if this assumption is right or wrong. Does your application limit the number of concurrent connections?

Comment: App does not (intentionally) limit connections.  For source code see question "what causes this CLOSE_WAIT".

Comment: The source code snippets in the [other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/687068/330217) are not sufficient to analyze the problem. I now voted to close the question because it lacks details.

Comment: Please add all the additional information from the comments to the question (use `edit`) and then remove the comments (use `delete`).

Answer (score 0):

There is no such limit (well, there *is*, but it's way beyond the 40,000 connection limit even for a vanilla system).

What there **is**, though, is [a limit on the **socket backlog**](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/listen.2.html) plus serviced connection (in the case of multi-threaded servers).

To verify, run `strace` on your binary and grep the output for the line with the `listen(x,y)` call. Connections in CLOSE_WAIT state may count against the total backlog, so if this is too low, a *normal* number of CLOSE_WAIT's might stop the server from accepting new connections.

CLOSE_WAIT means that the *client* has closed the connection, but the server hasn't yet released the socket. Any thread or resource connected to that socket is still busy. Usually, for a server, this does not make sense - once the connection has been terminated, the process ought to terminate as fast as it can. If it doesn't, then this means there is some problem at the code level (while TIME_WAIT could be adjusted at the kernel level). See, for example, [this article](https://developpaper.com/server-time_wait-and-close_wait-analysis-and-solution/).

You *can* sometimes reduce the CLOSE_WAIT linger time (see [here](https://www.programmersought.com/article/74221875444/)), but the real problem lies in the code and ought to be solved there.

Increasing the number of connection that can be served would also require acting on the server code - it might be some simple configuration directive (such as MaxConnections) or it might even mean an architectural change.

In some cases it might be possible to put a multiplexer such as [redir](https://github.com/troglobit/redir) in front of the server (that is: you run the original program on port, say, 127.0.0.1:12225, then instruct redir to listen to connections on 0.0.0.0:2225 and redirect them to 127.0.0.1:12225), and this will "cure" some kinds of connection mishaps that can lead to an excessive number of CLOSE_WAITs.

Comment: as the netstat shows, there is only one pending connection. backlog is set to 5, how would this result in a 10 connection limit?

Comment: @jcz I do not know, but CLOSE_WAIT problems can't be fixed by tuning kernel parameters -- it's something in the code. Where could I find this mdp program you're using? It's not the standard mdp package and I guess it's not the node/mdp package either.

Comment: see my question"what causes this CLOSE_WAIT"

Comment: @jcz added some explanations and a couple suggestions. I'd still like to see this mdp program for myself ;-)

Comment: did you look at "what causes this CLOSE_WAIT"?

Comment: @jcz only in a general sense. **The problem is in the program code**, so I'd need to look at the code. Which, not knowing where the program comes from, I can't.

Comment: the code is there